# PostgreSQL table to big? Insufficient memory?

Tags: postgresql, error-handling

I have a table with ~ 3.8 million rows.  When I query the entire table, I get

> ERROR: value overflows numeric format

referring to the value returned by a user-defined function.
But if I divide the table roughly in half (see below) everything works fine.

```
SELECT day,item,price,
    CAST(my_func(price) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY day) AS numeric(8,2)),
    FROM my_table
    --WHERE day < '3/1/2013';
    --WHERE day >= '3/1/2013';
```

The statement with either `WHERE` clause executes without the error.

Price is `numeric(8,2)` and there aren't any numbers in the price column bigger than `numeric(8,2)`.  In any case, changing the format to `numeric(20,2)` made no difference.

Here's the table definition:

```
    CREATE TABLE my_table
    (
        item    character(5)    NOT NULL,
        day     date            NOT NULL,
        price   numeric(8,2),
        CONSTRAINT  my_table_pk PRIMARY KEY (item, day)
    );
```

...and the function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func2 (avg numeric, IN price numeric)
    RETURNS numeric AS $$
    DECLARE
        alpha numeric;
    BEGIN
        alpha := 2.0/51;
        RETURN
            CASE
                WHEN avg IS NULL THEN price  -- avg is NULL for the first row, so price is returned
                ELSE round((alpha * price + (1-alpha) * avg),2)
            END;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE PLPgSQL;
```

...is used in an aggregate:

```
    CREATE AGGREGATE my_func(numeric) (SFUNC = my_func2, STYPE = numeric);
```

Comment: Evidently, I don't have enough juice to edit my question.

Comment: Whoever does, please fix the layout of the query.  Not sure how the return characters got lost.  Thx.

Comment: Thanks, Abelisto, that looks great.

Comment: Looks like either a failed cast or some kind of numeric overflow in `my_func()`. I'd be surprised if the row count has anything to do with it. `WHERE day IS NULL` isn't covered by either of your conditions; is the problematic record one of those? What happens when you run `SELECT * FROM my_table`?

Comment: As suggested by @NickBarnes try `WHERE day IS NULL`. The message error refers to the numeric format you are imposing (`numeric(8,2)`) and tells you that your number can't be casted to fit those lengths. Try to not cast or cast to `real` and see what happens. Also, try a different decimal length (for example `numeric(8,10)`). PS 3.8 millions rows isn't big.

Comment: Nick and pietrop, many thanks for your replies.  Doesn't the fact that the query works on each half of the table demonstrate that there are no NULL values?

Comment: Butselect * from my_table where day IS NULL;

Comment: ...returns 0 rows.

Comment: My point is:  There ISN'T a "problematic record".  Some second-order weirdness is going on.  Maybe.

Comment: @Bandersnatch please post table definition (the `CREATE TABLE` statement of `my_table`) and the definition of `my_func()`.

Comment: Nick, thanks again. Select * delivered 3.8 million rows.pietrop

Comment: pietrop - coming up.

Comment: @Bandersnatch after writing a comment you have few minutes to edit it and add other sentences. Try to not write chat-like comments here, please :) Anyway, I wrote an answer. Feel free to ask anything

Comment: I found only one situation that reproduced the exactly error with text you provided: `select 10::numeric ^ 140000;` and `ERROR:  value overflows numeric format`. It seems that you operate with extra large numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your cast operation. The format `numeric(8,2)` is very restrictive and probably `my_func()` returns values that don't satisfy the format definition. To demonstrate this, look at the following queries:

```
select 12.34::numeric(8,2);
 numeric 
---------
   12.34

select 12.345678::numeric(8,2);
 numeric 
---------
   12.35

select 12.3456789::numeric(8,2);
 numeric 
---------
   12.35

select 123456.123456789::numeric(8,2);
  numeric  
-----------
 123456.12

select 1234567.123456789::numeric(8,2);
ERROR:  numeric field overflow
DETAIL:  A field with precision 8, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^6.

select 1234567.8::numeric(8,2);
ERROR:  numeric field overflow
DETAIL:  A field with precision 8, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^6.
```

If you notice, the overall digits of the *returned* number never exceed `8` digits and always have `2` decimal digits. The last two queries give errors because they should have returned more than `8` digits. For example, you expect the number `1234567.123456789` to be rounded as `1234567.12` but `1234567.12` is composed by `9` digits, not `8`. The same is for the number `1234567.8`, even if you have `8` digits in it. This is because in the *returned* numeric value you want `2` decimal digits and so postgres sohuld output `1234567.80` but again, here you have `9` digits instead of `8`.

In other words, you have different ways to solve this issue:

1. Increase the overall decimal digits you expect from `my_func()` by using `numeric(16,2)` for `16` overall digits (choose the number you want).
2. Use a different numeric format, for example `numeric` or `real`. For example: `(my_func(price) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY day))::real`
3. If you need a specific decimal length and an unlimited overal digit number, try `round(my_func(price) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY day), 2)`. Otherwise, edit `my_func()` to return `round(returned_value, 2)`.

To help you understand and/or find why you get the error, consider this. For at least one or row at which `my_func()` is evaluated, you get a number with more than `6` digits on the left side. To find which row generate the error, you can simply execute this query:

```
WITH not_casted AS (
    SELECT day,item,price,
    my_func(price) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY day) AS fprice
    FROM my_table
)
SELECT * FROM not_casted
WHERE fprice > 999999.99
```

The rows returned by this query generate the cast error. Obviously this works if you don't typecast to `numeric(8,2)` inside `my_func()`, otherwise the error is generated on the value you are typecasting. Without knowing the function code it's impossible to make other assumptions.

### UPDATE

I propose an example based on a simulation. The code does the following:
 - create different `AGGREGATE` that have different typecasting and rounding approaches
 - execute each `AGGREGATE` on a simulated random sample that acts as your data (hopefully). It generates `10` prices per day, each of them has his own `item` for a total of `10` items over `31` days. This isn't really important in order to demonstrate the precision loss, so don't blame me if the data isn't correctly simulated :)

Here's the code to create the four functions and aggregates:

```
-- typecast price and arithmetics to numeric(8,2)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func_numeric_8_2_a (avg numeric(8,2), IN price numeric(8,2))
RETURNS numeric(8,2) AS $$
DECLARE
    alpha numeric;
BEGIN
    alpha := 2.0/51;
    RETURN
        CASE
            WHEN avg IS NULL THEN price
            ELSE (alpha * price + (1-alpha) * avg)::numeric(8,2)
        END;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPgSQL;
CREATE AGGREGATE my_func_numeric_8_2(numeric(8,2)) (SFUNC = my_func_numeric_8_2_a, STYPE = numeric(8,2));


-- typecast price and arithmetics to numeric and round(arithmetics, 2)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func_numeric_round_a(avg numeric, IN price numeric)
RETURNS numeric AS $$
DECLARE
    alpha numeric;
BEGIN
    alpha := 2.0/51;
    RETURN
    CASE
        WHEN avg IS NULL THEN price
            ELSE round((alpha * price + (1-alpha) * avg), 2)
        END;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPgSQL;
CREATE AGGREGATE my_func_numeric_round(numeric) (SFUNC = my_func_numeric_round_a, STYPE = numeric);

-- no typecast (double precision type)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func_dp_a(avg double precision, IN price double precision)
RETURNS double precision AS $$
DECLARE
    alpha double precision;
BEGIN
    alpha := 2.0/51;
    RETURN
    CASE
        WHEN avg IS NULL THEN price
            ELSE (alpha * price + (1-alpha) * avg)
        END;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPgSQL;
CREATE AGGREGATE my_func_dp(double precision) (SFUNC = my_func_dp_a, STYPE = double precision);

-- typecast price and arithmetics to numeric
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func_numeric_a(avg numeric, IN price numeric)
RETURNS numeric AS $$
DECLARE
    alpha numeric;
BEGIN
    alpha := 2.0/51;
    RETURN
    CASE
        WHEN avg IS NULL THEN price
            ELSE (alpha * price + (1-alpha) * avg)
        END;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPgSQL;
CREATE AGGREGATE my_func_numeric(numeric) (SFUNC = my_func_numeric_a, STYPE = numeric);
```

Now, the code to simulate data and apply the three functions:

```
WITH sample AS
(
    SELECT "day", (random())*10 AS price, generate_series(1,10)::text AS item
    FROM (SELECT generate_series('2000-01-01'::timestamp, '2000-01-31'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval)::date AS "day") AS calendar
)
SELECT  "day", item, price,
        -- typecast price and arithmetics to numeric(8,2)
        my_func_numeric_8_2(price::numeric(8,2))  OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY "day") AS numeric_8_2,

        -- typecast price and arithmetics to numeric and round(arithmetics, 2)
        my_func_numeric_round(price::numeric)  OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY "day") AS numeric_round,

        -- typecast price and arithmetics to numeric and round the final result
        round(my_func_numeric(price::numeric)  OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY "day"), 2) AS round_numeric,

        -- no typecast (double precision type)
        my_func_dp(price)  OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY "day") AS no_typecast,

        -- typecast price and arithmetics to numeric
        my_func_numeric(price::numeric)  OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY "day") AS numeric
FROM sample
ORDER BY item, "day"
```

Every query execution generates different results due to the usage of `random()`. Scroll down the results and you'll see many rows having different values, even if `price` is the same used for calculating all four values. Also, the columns are ordered by decreasing precision loss (or increasing precision): `my_func_dp(price)` is the most precise between the four, while `my_func_numeric_8_2(price::numeric(8,2))` is the less precise, but the most "exact".

If you run the previous query from the command line, you'll notice that `my_func_numeric(price::numeric)` returns numbers with increasing length, because `numeric` is exact as far as it can be possible, so his fixed length can vary. If you execute it from pgAdmin, you'll get a rounded number insted of the full length number.

[image: Screenshot of a portion of the simulated results.]

Comment: pietrop, I really do appreciate your answer. But the fact that the query runs correctly on the two halves of the table (see the two WHERE clauses in the query) means this can't be the reason for the error.  Doesn't it?

Comment: I have tried your suggestion 1.  I'll go try 2 and 3 just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: The problem simply is due to `my_func()` working on more rows and so returning bigger numbers that exceed the `8` digits you are imposing with `numeric(8,2)`. In other words, `numeric(8,2)` is too restrictive format and should be changed.

Comment: I should have mentioned that my_func only works on 2 rows.  It multiplies each by a number less than 1 and then adds them.
BUT I edited my_func to round the result, (which let me get rid of the CAST) and for whatever reason, the query now runs correctly on the whole table.
I wish I understood what the problem was, but I thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Bandersnatch I've updated my answer to give you a way to put some light on the issue. Please, if you find it useful and solved your issue, press the accept button.

Comment: pietrop, thanks for the update.  I ran the query that you added above, and it returned zero rows.  Moreover the max value of fprice is 226533.00.
I'll probably update the column format to give price some more room, but the bottom line is there aren't any numbers in the table that won't fit into numeric(8,2). Still a mystery...

Comment: @Bandersnatch To clarify this you have to post the table definition and the function code. I suspect that `number(8,2)` is used somewhere else :)

Comment: @Bandersnatch copy and paste the code into your initial question (press the `Edit` button below the question), save it and then delete your answer in order to make it easier for us to read through the whole story :) btw, you are using `numeric(8,2)` as the datatype for `price`. The error you got before introducing `round()` came from the sum of two `numeric(8,2)` numbers. Probably your algorithm doesn't work as you expect: you are partitioning by `item` but how big is the biggest partition? This can make `avg` grow up and exceed the 6 digits imposed by `numeric(8,2)`..

Comment: Also, why don't you use a safer and more perfomant datatype like `real`? The sideback of using a fixed size numeric format is also excess of rounding and loosing precision when concatening arithmetic operations like you do (sums and moltiplication), especially in your case: you want only two digits but alpha is `~0.03921569`. Your precision domain is far away from only 2 decimal digits..

Comment: I'm a novice here and I used numeric because the PgSQL documentation recommends it for monetary amounts "where exactness is required".  I'm not opposed to using real, though.
Are you saying arithmetic on real numbers would not need to be rounded? I thought I read that the scale of the result is s1+s2 for decimal types?

Comment: @Bandersnatch it is your choice to choose an exact format against a more precise one. The question here is: do you need exactness or precision when doing arithmetic operations? `price` must be exact, but should `alpha * price + (1-alpha) * avg` be exact or precise? If I'm not wrong, you're nesting arithmetic operations: `avg` is the result of the previous evaluation on the same `PARTITION`. Rounding at `2` digits leads you to loose *a lot* of precision while mantaining exactness. If you need exactness, than modify the table definition to allow greater values for `price`.

Comment: I think it would be fine to have all results be accurate to the nearest .01.  Please explain how using numeric vs real requires excess of rounding?  Would the real format return results of computations rounded to just two decimal places?  Also, is there a way to make PostgreSQL display the actual value that "overflows numeric format"?

Comment: @Bandersnatch read my update. The difference between `real` and pure `numeric` is quite subtle. The query I propose in my update helps you understand how much precision you loose (as far as I have seen for your formula, it ranges from `0.00` to `0.02`). You can also see how `numeric` differs from `double precision` (or `real` if you want to try it). The docs states that `numeric` is `user-specified precision, exact` while `double precision` is `variable-precision, inexact`. Read "8.1.2. Arbitrary Precision Numbers" https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: Pietro, all I can say is "Wow"! Thank you for your clear and impressive explanation of the subtleties involved here. I understand now what you were saying, and I'll change the function and data table accordingly.
Thanks again and ciao! :-)